# Is there a way to overload math function for a custom type?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

I know you can do operator overloading (+-*/) for a custom type. Is there a way to do the same for custom math function as well? This would make vector operation more natural (like in R). Example:

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

vector + vector = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]  # can be achieved with operator overloading
vector * 5 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] # can be achieved with operator overloading

pow(vector, 2) = [ 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 ]  # is it possible in C#?
```

**update**
From the answers below I see that "function overloading" is not possible (probably doesn't make much sense) and the best way to handle that is to create custom math function library (static class).
That solution is fine, although is there a way to reuse "custom functions" with other custom types? Say I have numbers (int/float), complex numbers, vectors and matrices (array of vectors). I want my Pow function to work with all 4 types (it should power each numeric element in the object).
Also, is there a way to have function to do different things based on the input type? For example

```
abs(-1) = 1  # for integer abs just change the sign if negative
abs(4+3i) = sqrt(4^2+3^2) = 5 # smth different for complex number
```

Comment: You just write your own `pow` method. Does that not satisfy your wants?

Comment: That, or you can overload the `^` operator, but it could bring some confusion.

Comment: No, it's just pseudo code. Say I have standard math library that works with  integers/floats, wondering if there is a way reuse it with vector type.

Comment: pow is just an example. I want to use it with other functions like sin, cos, sqrt, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like this by utilizing the `using static` feature added in C# 6.  This allows you to make static methods from a class available without having to specify the type name.  (The .NET `Math` class is frequently cited as an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) for this feature.)

Assuming a `Vector` class that implements `IEnumerable<double>`, you can create a class containing your static `Pow` function:

```
namespace Vectors
{
    public static class VectorMath
    {
        public static Vector Pow(Vector v, int exponent)
        {
            return new Vector(v.Select(n => Math.Pow(n, exponent)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in any code file where you want to use this class, include the statement

```
using static Vectors.VectorMath;
```

This will allow you to call the `Pow` method without needing to specify that it is a member of the `VectorMath` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector v = new Vector { 1, 2, 3 };
        Vector squares = Pow(v, 2);

        // Squares now contains [1, 4, 9]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, at least method is detached from vector class (I'd say it's my primary requirement). Ideally I would like to make all math function (or custom set of function) to work with vector type in one shot (rather than create wrapper for each function). It's probably impossible, just want to make sure I'm not missing some magic trick

Comment: @MikeTwc This is unfortunately impossible, math is beyond power of generics in C#. You can see this in the LINQ where e.g. [Enumerable.Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) has overloads for all numeric types and their nullable variants. You may perhaps be able to extract some common semantics but if you think about it in the end, functions such as `Pow` have type-specific implementation (usually down to the platform's instruction set) so there's not much point in providing generic software implementation on framework level.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension method pow() for Array class

```
 public static class VecorExtension
{
        public static void pow(this Array vector, int i)
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

usage:

> [1,2,3].pow(2);

[Extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: I'm afraid that this will add the extension method to all `Array` types which could be very counter-intuitive, not to mention the implementation complexity.